# kafka consumer polling not return all data many times

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am polling to kafka consumer as follows.

```
val records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(5000)).asScala.toList
```

This sometimes bring message. Sometimes not. I am repeatedly calling a method many times in which I am consuming data from topic. Shall I set `"max.partition.fetch.bytes" to "5048576"` or there is problem with something else?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean with "sometimes bring message". Can you describe in which situations you are able to consume message in which not?

Comment: I have automation test. so In one  step I publish data to producer and in next step I conssume data from topic. so when I am reading data from consumer, I sometimes get data from topic sometimes not using poll though I can see producer has already published data

Answer (score 1):

Polling is not guaranteed to return records; it is guaranteed to block and wait for records.

You need to check if there is another consumer that is part of the same consumer group that is already consuming messages that you might expect.

---

In the comments, you mention a test, and Kafka provides a MockConsumer and MockProducer class for a unittesting scenario. Kafka Streams also has its own testing methods